# time on ecos (or qemu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, time, ecos

I'm working with real time operating system Ecos.
I run this code on Ubuntu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int tv_diff(struct timeval *t1, struct timeval *t2)
{
    return
        (t1->tv_sec - t2->tv_sec) * 1000 +
        (t1->tv_usec - t2->tv_usec) / 1000;
}

int main(void)
{
struct timespec ts;
struct timeval tv1, tv2;

printf("Hello, eCos !\n");

clock_gettime(1, &ts);
tv1.tv_sec = ts.tv_sec;
tv1.tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
printf("Time: %ld \n", tv1.tv_sec);
sleep(10);
clock_gettime(1, &ts);
tv2.tv_sec = ts.tv_sec;
tv2.tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000;

printf("Time: %ld \n", tv2.tv_sec);

printf("diff Time: %d \n", tv_diff(&tv2, &tv1));

    return 0;
}
```

and it worked  properly:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/feres/Bureau# ./amin
Hello, eCos !
Time: 45417 
Time: 45427 
diff Time: 10000
```

but when I run it on ecos (which it work with on qemu) it give me these results:

```
Hello, eCos !
Time: 0 
Time: 0 
diff Time: 0
```

is there any missing package on ecos (or qemu) or is there any specific command to get time on ecos (or qemu)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ECOS-HAL is not correctly set up (so that the system tick gets updated on a regular basis).